# How do I fadeIn rows one by one?

Tags: jquery

I have this code and it works, but I am trying to add callback to it so that each row fades in- one after one. Right now the whole table is fading in.

```
function foo() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        $(".Table tr").eq(i).fadeIn(3000);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    foo()
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('.Table tr').slice(0, 5).each(function(i, row) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(row).fadeIn(3000);
    }, 3000 * i);
});
```

It delays each fade-in by 3s.

Answer (score 0):

The `fadeIn` function can take a callback to run when complete as a second argument.

Something like

```
var showNextRow = function(){
   var nextInvisibleRow = $('.Table tr').not(':visible').filter(':first');
   if( nextInvisibleRow.length > 0 ){
       nextInvisibleRow.fadeIn(3000, showNextRow); 
   }
}
showNextRow();
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamconway/eqymz4e4/)

[fadeIn docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)